# Extract Deploy Data from Firebase Deploy

Tags: node.js, deployment, build

I have a unique problem that needs a fix quickly for a client.

I made a large chunk of changes to a client website before launch and I was able to deploy to firebase before my computer crashed and the hard drive is bust. I wasn't able to push my changes to Github so I only have what is live on the site and the Firebase deploy. I would love to extract the data from the live site/firebase if possible so I do not have to recreate all the changes I made. I am using the MERN stack for the web app.

Is it possible to extract the built files that were deployed to Firebase?